# How does startssl.com authentication work?

Tags: curl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, handshake

Startssl.com, which provides free class 1 ssl certs, uses a very unique and simple authentication system. During it's login process it redirects the client to https://auth.startssl.com/ and the browser asks for their unique certificate. After that stage is finished they are redirected to their control panel without any username/password authentication.

[image: cert request]

**I wasn't even aware that HTTP(s) could do this type of authentication natively!**

I've tried using `curl` to dissect this request but I can't get a value HTTPS request to go through.

```
X:~ ken$ curl https://auth.startssl.com/ --cert ./startssl-id.crt 
curl: (58) unable to set private key file: './startssl-id.crt' type PEM
```

Does curl support this type of HTTPS connection and if so how would it be configured on both the server and client side?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a client-side certificate. In order to watch the traffic, your user agent needs to support client side certificates. If you just want to watch the network traffic, you could look using your browser's network traffic log, but that won't include the cert negotiation.

curl does support client side certificates. You use them like this:

```
curl --cert mycert.pem https://secure.example.com
```

If you really want to get into the nitty gritty of the packet negotiation, your best bet is probably to use wireshark to dissect the packets.

The docs for configuring this in Apache are here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol

Comment: I tried using the `--cert` option, but I'm not sure how to get from the file they give you during registration to a file that curl can use.

Comment: `openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.crt -out certificate.pem`

Comment: `X:StartSSL ken$ openssl x509 -inform der -in ./startssl-id.crt -out ./startssl-id.pem
unable to load certificate
140735182842300:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140735182842300:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509`

Answer (score 0):

This page has a good how to on adding client cert authentication to any web app:

https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2013/11/adding-easy-ssl-client-authentication-to-any-webapp/

as for making client certs work with curl - you'll probably need to convert the certificate from pkcs12 format to a plain private key and certificate, using openssl i've done this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -in startcom.p12 -out start.pem -info -nodes
```

where startcom.p12 was exported from Firefox (I don't have a mac so can't test with Safari).

and then I can:

```
openssl s_client -connect auth.startssl.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -cert /tmp/start.pem -key /tmp/start.key -prexit -debug -msg -state -servername auth.startssl.com -tlsextdebug
```

which connects, and:

```
wget --verbose --debug --ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs/ --certificate=/tmp/start.pem --private-key=/tmp/start.key  https://auth.startssl.com/
```

also works.